# "Sold out" error message when registering event with PayPal payment (event is not full though)

Tags: civievent, civimember, payment-processor, paypal

I'd be grateful for any pointers regarding an issue with event registration, using PayPal Pro, when paying with a PayPal account (paying with a credit card, also using PayPal Pro processor works just fine).

The **user experience**: fill out event registration info, click the PayPal button, log into PayPal and submit the payment, back on the confirmation page click on Continue.

The **result**: user gets the following error messages (which are incorrect as the event is not sold out):

> Unfortunately some of your options have now sold out for one or more
>   participants. You have been returned to the start of the registration
>   process and any sold out events have been removed from your
>   selections. You will not be able to continue until you review your
>   booking and select different events if you wish. Sold out: Please note
>   that the options which are marked or selected are sold out for
>   participant being viewed.

System:
Joomla 3.4.1
CiviCRM 4.6.2

Any ideas on what I could check on? Thanks a million, P

Answer (score 2):

The error is because the max participant limit is reached for the price option.

You probably need to check the Max Participant limit in your Price set/field

Comment: thank you for your suggestion; the Max Participant limit for this field is null; also, folks can register just fine when paying with a credit card (via the PayPal Pro payment processor) but get this error message when paying with PayPal (also via the PayPal Pro payment processor)

Comment: I have tried leaving the Max Participant Limit field null as well as 999 and I am experiencing the same problem as MtnPavlas. I am on CiviCRM 4.6.2 on Joomla 3.4.1.

Unfortunately some of your options have now sold out for one or more participants. You have been returned to the start of the registration process and any sold out events have been removed from your selections. You will not be able to continue until you review your booking and select different events if you wish.

Sold out: Please note that the options which are marked or selected are sold out for participant being viewed.

Comment: Looking through the code it looks like it might be failing on the formRule. The form is not saving variables (possibly $form->_feeBlock) in such a way as to make them accessible when the browser returns. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Confirm.php

Comment: Just hit this issue too. null participants.

Comment: @KLDavenport - you should make your comment an answer.  The OP says that this is not sold out.  This is a bug I think.

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. I have both a credit card payment gateway, and we offer PayPal Express as a secondary gateway. When using a credit card (form post), it works fine. When using PayPal Express, it gives the sold out error (civi 4.6.4).

Comment: My comment is not an answer it's just a though, either way I have no way of playing around or implementing this in the CiviCRM.

Comment: Issue submitted here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17015

Answer (score 2):

The bug was fixed by Yashodha of the core team in 4.6.9:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17015

In the mean time, there is a 3 line patch that you can apply:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6720/files